# Can I access '\n' using a Scanner object in Java?

Tags: java

I try to write the contents of a file into a string, so I use a Scanner object to read the contents.Like this:

```
Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(sourceFile);
StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
```

Then I used the function .Next() to read the contents of the file, and add it to contents using `contents.append(sourceFile);`

But I find there is no '\n' or space in the String `contents`.
I think it is because function .Next() ignores space and '\n', is that correct? And how can I access '\n' in the input stream?

Answer (score 1):

Add the new line character to the StringBuilder after you add the line you read from the file:

`contents.append(scanFile.next() + "\n")`

Comment: What if I want to read all the '\n' ? I mean there are many lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.next()` read string from input until it reach an space or new line character, if you want to read file line by line you must use `Sacnner.nextLine()`, see [Scanner Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
for example if your input file contains :

```
foo bar foo
bar baz
```

using `next()` method you get 5 `foo`, `bar`, `foo`, `bar`, `bar`
using `nextLine()` method you get `foo bar foo`, `bar baz`